# powershell restart service if failed

Tags: powershell, service, crash, restart

i have the Problem that an Service is crashing whitout stopping.
This means the status is shown as running but...

However - i wrote a small (absolute Beginner(!)-)Powershell-Script to check if the app is crashed, but how do i have to continue?

If the Script finds an entry in the Eventlog it shoud stop and start the Service..

```
Clear-Host
$timetocheck = [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(-10)
$eventid = "10016"
$log = "System"
$app = "SID"
$check = "Get-WinEvent -LogName $log | Where-Object {($_.TimeCreated -ge $timetocheck) -and ($_.id -eq $eventid) -and  ($_.Message -Like *$app*)}"
```

*edit*

just to clarify -

if this snippet finds nothing in the eventlog nothing should happen.

if this snippet finds at least 1 error in the eventlog the service should be stopped and restarted.

with other words - if process crashed restart else do nothing

thx

Comment: sorry - at this moment i doesn´t understand the logic...
i´ve tryed this:

`Clear-Host`
`$timetocheck = [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(-5000)`
`$eventid = "10016"`
`$log = "System"`
`$app = "SID"`
`#$process = Get-Process notepad #PDTMScan*`
`$checking = Get-WinEvent $log | Where-Object{``
`($_.TimeCreated -ge $timetocheck) -and ``
`($_.id -eq $eventid) -and  ``
`($_.Message -Like "*$app*")}`

`$checking | Out-File d:\111\checking.txt`
`$checking -contains "$eventid"`

This returns **false**

Comment: the file **checking.txt** looks like this:



_   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message                                                                          
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------                                                                          
16.04.2015 10:15:26          10016 Fehler           Durch die Berechtigungseinstellungen (application-specific) wird der SID (S-1-..._

here i can find the string 10016 - why does it returns false? i expected here a true....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - now i can answer my own question.. ;)

This works:

```
Clear-Host
$timetocheck = [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(-30)
$eventid = "10016"
$log = "System"
$app = "SID"
$checking = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname="$log";ID="$eventid" ;StartTime="$timetocheck"}|`
Where-Object {$_.Message -like "*$app*"}
if ($checking -like "*") {ReStart-Service -Name DistributedCOM -Force}
```

The Trick is the **$checking -like "*"**. I´m not satisfied completely because this "only" checks if the *Get-Winevent* replys at least one sign. I would prefer to search for a string i know....

When the string to check is shorter its working with a defined string....

However - its working. And thats important. And maybe someone else needs this to.

thx to all

*edit*
and the first improvment....

the command **Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname="$log";ID="$eventid" ;StartTime="$timetocheck"}| Where-Object {$_.Message -like "*$app*"}**
takes *0,7 seconds*

the command **Get-WinEvent $log | Where-Object{($*.TimeCreated -ge $timetocheck) -and ($*.id -eq $eventid) -and ($_.Message -Like "*$app*")}** takes *4,2 seconds*

so i changed it

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the following code

```
Clear-Host
$timetocheck = [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(-10)
$eventid = "10016"
$log = "System"
$app = "SID"
$check = Get-WinEvent -LogName $log | Where-Object {($_.TimeCreated -ge $timetocheck) -and ($_.id -eq $eventid) -and  ($_.Message -Like "*$app*")}

if ($check -ne $null)
{
    Restart-Service -Name YourService -Force
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work properly

i´ve replaced for testing

`restart-service`
with 
`write-host "error"`

and the message is everytime here - even if the time is set to 0